# Transforming a 1D console style program into a 2D GUI interface

Tags: java, swing, 2d

So I have a program that is essentially a console style program that prints out lines related to the results of the simulation.
The simulation simply records the motion of a car travelling along a road in which stops at a traffic light if red, then proceeds onto the next road when the traffic light turns green.

My question is, where the hell would one start in turning this text style simulation into a GUI interface?

I am familiar with the components of swing, and I'm not asking for a full breakdown, but just a kick-starter in where I would need to start to begin transforming this program. Thanks!

Comment: *"I'm not asking for a full breakdown, but just a kick-starter"* See [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

Since your code already produces the correct Data, there is no need to redo all the simulation. I would take a look at the Three-tier architecture (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitier_architecture#Three-tier_architecture). I design most of my applications like this, so exchanging for example the Presentation to the user is pretty easy and does not require touching any of the code which is not especially designed to display data to the user.

How you described your Application, you might ignore the Data tier. If I got you right, you are not reading or storing persistent data. If you have for example some physical properties you should read them from the Data tier. If you want to store the result of the Simulation, once again you need the Data tier.

The Logic tier is your actual simulation of the car, the traffic light and possibly the roads.

The Presentation tier takes predefined Objects from the Logic tier and does nothing than presenting it to the User.

If you stick to this Design, it does not matter wheter your UI is on Console, Swing, JavaFX or a Website. You can swap it back and fort at will.